# Magento 2. How to add recently viewed products programmatically

Tags: products, magento-2.0, view

I have a page with a custom layout and I want to add Recently Viewed Products to one of the blocks on that page. How do I do it programmatically, e.g. using my own phtml template?
In Magento 1.9x it was super easy to do. In Magento 2 this function added using widget, but I cannot find the way to add it to my custom page.
Regards!

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new static block and call it in your phtml file, So do the following step :
Navigate **Content->Blocks** = create a new block and **add recently viewed products widget** in it and save the block and call in in your phtml file using following code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('your_block_Identifier')->toHtml();?>
```

clear your cache and refresh the page.

Done !

Comment: I tried this one but it's not working. I'm using Magento 2.1.1

Comment: Not working in Magento 2.1.1